# $f(N) = 10^{n-1} \times ( N\mod{10}) + \frac{N - (N\mod{10}) }{10}$. Find $N$ such that $f(N) = \frac{2}{3}N$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> $f(N) = 10^{n-1} \times ( N\mod{10}) + \frac{N - (N\mod{10}) }{10}$.  Where $n$ = number of digits in $N$
>   Find smallest $N$ such that $f(N) = \frac{2}{3}N$

I am stuck at the beginning. Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The function is just taking the last digit to the first. i.e. If $N = 1234$ then $f(N) = 4123$. 
**Full Solution**: 
Let the number $10x+y$, where $y$ is the last digit and $10x$ is the rest.
So, $$ \frac{2 \times (10x +y )}{3} = y \times 10^{n-1} + x \\ 
       \text{simplify} \\
        \cdots \cdots \cdots \\
      \frac{x}{y} = \frac{3\times10^{n-1} -2}{17}$$
So, ${3\times10^{n-1} -2}$ must be divisible by $17$. Here the least possible value of $n$ is $16$!
Thus, $$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{3 \times10^{15} - 2}{17}$$
As we need the smallest value, so set $y = 1$ and then $x = 176470588235294$
So, $N = 1764705882352941$

Comment: Still can't solve it :(

Comment: Wait for the full solve. :)

Comment: Ow. Really !! Smallest $N = 1764705882352941$ o.O Are you kidding! I was trying to plug some number and test ! :) Nice Solution.